# How to create a list that exceeds the maximum size in Python

Tags: python, list

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get), *The maximum size of a Python list on a 32 bit system is 536,870,912 elements*.

Is there any possible way to initialize a list with bigger size than that?

Let's say:

```
list1 = [None]*1000000000
```

Comment: Well, no, that's what a "maximum size" means. You can `itertools.chain` a bunch of chunks together, I guess, if you have the memory.

Comment: Did you take into account that each element of a list, at the very least, occupies 4 bytes, thus `4 * 536,870,912 = 2147483648`. Now That's 2GB of RAM just for the list. If the elements are not identical I'm pretty sure you'll get a MemoryError way before reaching that size.

Comment: @bakuriu thank you for pointing that out. I did get a MemoryError. :(

Answer (score 19):

Lists that large would take up a massive amount of space, as each element in the list would occupy at least 4 bytes, so just one list with maximum allowed elements would take up minimum 2GB of RAM<sup>1</sup>. And that's without even considering 64-bit systems<sup>2</sup>.

1. `4 * 5.4e+8 = 2.1e+9`, 2.1 GB
2. `8 * 1.2e+18 = 9.2e+18`, 9.2 EB (yes, exabytes)

However, for the sake of the question, let's assume that you have a lot of RAM.

---

One of the simplest options would be to create you own object to hold and handle the massive list. It would basically split the massive list into smaller lists, and then access them accordingly when needed. As there are [no real benefits of subclassing `list`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3946763/2801037) because you'd have to rewrite all of the methods anyway, you'd be better of just subclassing `object` and then go from there. The only thing that is essential here is to never combine or copy the sub-lists (because they are massive), so use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to loop over the lists when necessary.

Here is an example of the most simple list-methods `append`, `extend`, `get/setitem` working:

```
import sys
from itertools import chain

class largeList(object):
    def __init__(self, mylist=None):
        self.maxSize = sys.maxsize/4
        self.src = [[]]
        self.extend(mylist if mylist is not None else [])

    def __iter__(self):
        return chain(*self.src)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.src[int(idx/self.maxSize)][idx%self.maxSize]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, item):
        self.src[int(idx/self.maxSize)][idx%self.maxSize] = item
        # expand set/getitem to support negative indexing.

    def append(self, item):
        if len(self.src[-1]) < self.maxSize:
            self.src[-1].append(item)
        else:
            self.src.append([item])
    
    def extend(self, items):
        remainder = self.maxSize - len(self.src[-1])
        self.src[-1].extend(items[:remainder])
        for i in xrange(0, len(items[remainder:]), self.maxSize):
            self.src.append(items[remainder:][i:i+self.maxSize])

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(len(l) for l in self.src)
    
    def __str__(self):
        size = self.__len__()
        if size >= 8:
            first, last = [], []
            for i, ele in enumerate(self.__iter__()):
                if i < 3:
                    first.append(ele)
                if i >= size - 3:
                    last.append(ele)
            return str(first)[:-1] + ', ..., ' + str(last)[1:]
        return str(list(self.__iter__()))
```

Example use (**if you have less than 4GB free RAM or you are on a 64-bit system, change `sys.maxsize` before trying this!**):

```
#sys.maxsize = 1000

list1 = largeList(xrange(sys.maxsize/4 + 2))
print len(list1)
# 53687093
print list1
#[0, 1, 2, ..., 536870910, 536870911, 536870912]
print list1.src
#[[0, 1, 2 ..., 536870910], [536870911, 536870912]]
list1.extend([42, 43])
print list1
#[0, 1, 2, ..., 536870912, 42, 43]
```

The result: internally the lists are split into multiple lists, while they appear to be just one when working with them. More `list` functionalities can easily be added by adding more methods. E.g. `pop`, `remove`, `insert`, and `index`:

```
(...)

    def pop(self, idx):
        listidx = int(idx/self.maxSize)
        itempopped = self.src[listidx].pop(idx%self.maxSize)
        for i in xrange(listidx, len(self.src)-1):
            self.src[i].append(self.src[i+1].pop(0))
        if not self.src[-1]:
            del self.src[-1]
        return itempopped
        
    def remove(self, item):
        for i, ele in enumerate(self.__iter__()):
            if ele == item:
                self.pop(i)
                break
    
    def insert(self, idx, item):
        listidx = int(idx/self.maxSize)
        itemtoshift = self.src[listidx].pop(-1)
        self.src[listidx].insert(idx%self.maxSize, item)
        for i in xrange(listidx+1, len(self.src)-1):
            itemremoved = self.src[i].pop(-1)
            self.src[i].insert(0, itemtoshift)
            itemtoshift = itemremoved
        if len(self.src[-1]) < self.maxSize:
            self.src[-1].insert(0, itemtoshift)
        else:
            self.src.append([self.src[-1].pop(-1)])
            self.src[-2].insert(0, itemtoshift)
    
    def index(self, item):
        for i, ele in enumerate(self.__iter__()):
            if ele == item:
                return i
        return -1
```

Example use, continued:

```
#sys.maxsize = 1000

list1 = largeList(xrange(sys.maxsize/4 + 2))
list1.insert(0, 'a')
print list1
#['a', 0, 1, ..., 536870910, 536870911, 536870912]
list1.pop(2)
#1
list1.remove(536870910)
print list1.index('a')
#0
print len(list1)
#536870911
print list1
#['a', 0, 2, ..., 536870909, 536870911, 536870912]
print list.src
#[['a', 0, 2, ..., 536870909, 536870911], [536870912]]
```

Comment: I would replace the default value of the parameter `mylist` with `None` and in the body of the `__init__` add `if mylist is None: self.mylist = []` to not cause any bugs

Comment: @LMCuber feel free to make the edit. :)