# Should I subclass list or create class with list as attribute?

Tags: python, list, subclass, extend

I need a container that can collect a number of objects and provides some reporting functionality on the container's elements. Essentially, I'd like to be able to do:

```
magiclistobject = MagicList()
magiclistobject.report()  ### generates all my needed info about the list content
```

So I thought of subclassing the normal list and adding a report() method. That way, I get to use all the built-in list functionality.

```
class SubClassedList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        list.__init__(self)
    
    
    def report(self):      # forgive the silly example
        if 999 in self:
            print "999 Alert!"
```

Instead, I could also create my own class that has a magiclist attribute but I would then have to create new methods for appending, extending, etc., if I want to get to the list using:

```
magiclistobject.append() # instead of magiclistobject.list.append()
```

I would need something like this (which seems redundant):

```
class MagicList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def append(self,element):
        self.list.append(element)

    def extend(self,element):
        self.list.extend(element)

# more list functionality as needed...
    
    def report(self):       
        if 999 in self.list:
            print "999 Alert!"
```

I thought that subclassing the list would be a no-brainer. But [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945940/what-to-consider-before-subclassing-list) makes it sounds like a no-no. Why?

Comment: As another alternative, you could skip classes entirely and write a `report(some_ordinary_list)` function.

Comment: Keep the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in mind when deciding whether or not to subclass.

Answer (score 14):

One reason why extending list might be bad is since it ties together your 'MagicReport' object too closely to the list. For example, a Python list supports the following methods:

```
append
count
extend
index
insert
pop
remove
reverse
sort
```

It also contains a whole host of other operations (adding, comparisons using `<` and `>`, slicing, etc).

Are all of those operations things that your 'MagicReport' object actually wants to support? For example, the following is legal Python:

```
b = [1, 2]
b *= 3
print b   # [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

This is a pretty contrived example, but if you inherit from 'list', your 'MagicReport' object will do exactly the same thing if somebody inadvertently does something like this.

As another example, what if you try slicing your MagicReport object?

```
m = MagicReport()

# Add stuff to m

slice = m[2:3]
print type(slice)
```

You'd probably expect the slice to be another MagicReport object, but it's actually a list. You'd need to override `__getslice__` in order to avoid surprising behavior, which is a bit of a pain.

---

It also makes it harder for you to change the implementation of your MagicReport object. If you end up needing to do more sophisticated analysis, it often helps to be able to change the underlying data structure into something more suited for the problem.

If you subclass list, you *could* get around this problem by just providing new `append`, `extend`, etc methods so that you don't change the interface, but you won't have any clear way of determining which of the list methods are actually being used unless you read through the entire codebase. However, if you use composition and just have a list as a field and create methods for the operations you support, you know exactly what needs to be changed.

I actually ran into a scenario very similar to your at work recently. I had an object which contained a collection of 'things' which I first internally represented as a list. As the requirements of the project changed, I ended up changing the object to internally use a dict, a custom collections object, then finally an OrderedDict in rapid succession. At least in my experience, composition makes it much easier to change how something is implemented as opposed to inheritance.

---

That being said, I think extending list might be ok in scenarios where your 'MagicReport' object is legitimately a list in all but name. If you *do* want to use MagicReport as a list in every single way, and don't plan on changing its implementation, then it just might be more convenient to subclass list and just be done with it.

Though in that case, it might be better to just use a list and write a 'report' function -- I can't imagine you needing to report the contents of the list more than once, and creating a custom object with a custom method just for that purpose might be overkill (though this obviously depends on what exactly you're trying to do)

Comment: +1 for suggesting a function. This is how Python does things anyways: for example, with `len()`. `len` actually calls an object's `__len__` method, but it's a function because it represents a duck-typed interface, a promise that `len`'s argument will have a length. Whether the objects are in a list or tuple (or maybe even a set) doesn't need to matter.

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, whenever you ask yourself "should I inherit or have a member of that type", choose not to inherit. This rule of thumb is known as "favour composition over inheritance".

The reason why this is so is: composition is appropriate where you want to use features of another class; inheritance is appropriate if other code needs to use the features of the other class with the class you are creating.