# How to inherit a class which is inheriting `list` with correct type hint in Python?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, type-hinting, python-typing

For example, I have two classes: `Animal` and `Cat`.

```py
class Animal:
    pass


class Cat(Animal):
    pass
```

Then, I would like to make a list of `Animal` so that I can write some functions to manage this list of `Animal`. It is intuitive to create a class here which inherits `list`.

```py
from typing import List


class AnimalList(List[Animal]):
    def get_element(self) -> Animal:  # get one element, just for example
        return self[0]
```

(I have read questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25328448/8868362), and I think inheriting list is likely to be what I want, rather than creating a class with list as attribute.)

After that, I found that I also need a class so that I can manage a list of `Cat`. `Cat` has some features that its base `Animal` does not have. So, I need both the functions in `AnimalList` and special functions which can only be done with a list of `Cat`. That is to say, I need a class `CatList` that satisfies the following requirements:

1. I can manage a list of `Cat`, just like what I do with `list`. For example, I can do something like:

```py
# I want to do something like:
cat = Cat()
cat_list = CatList()
cat_list.append(cat)  # manipulate this CatList like list
cat_1 = cat_list[0]
```

2. `CatList` can inherit methods in `AnimalList`, and also has its own methods. For example, I can do something like:

```py
# I want to do something like:
cat_list.play_with_cats()  # Own function

cat_2 = cat_list.get_element()  # Base function
```

3. type hint for `CatList.__getitem__()` (the `cat_1` above) is `Cat`
4. type hint for the result of base class methods like `CatList.get_element()` (the `cat_2` above) is `Cat`

**Question**: How to create a class `CatList` that satisfies the requirements above? What is the class that `CatList` is supposed to inherit?

I have tried several ways to do this.

**Attempt 1**

Inherit from `AnimalList`:

```py
class CatList(AnimalList):
    def play_with_cats(self) -> None:
        print("Play with cats!")
        
    def __getitem__(self, item) -> Cat:
        return self.__getitem__(item)
    
    def get_element(self) -> Cat:
        return super().get_element()
```

But I need to rewrite all functions like `__getitem__()`, `get_element()` to make sure that the corresponding type hint of these functions is `Cat`. This is too cumbersome.

**Attempt 2**

Inherit from both `List[Cat]` and `AnimalList`:

```py
class CatList(List[Cat], AnimalList):
    def play_with_cats(self) -> None:
        print("Play with cats!")
```

But the type hint for the result of `CatList.__getitem__()` and `get_element()` becomes `Any`, rather than `Cat`.

Comment: Haven't used it in Python yet, but you may be interested in looking at [Python's Generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) to help with this.

Comment: @kindall: No, that's not how it works. `class AnimalList(List[Animal]):` really does create a class whose instances are lists, not a type hint for lists. Try it - [at runtime](https://ideone.com/gsG7ha), you'll find that `AnimalList()` is an instance of `AnimalList`, which is a subclass of `list`, and if you try to [run a static type checker](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=0d29e7ea7682629a312570c7f7ceaf64) on your code, you'll find that it accepts code like `l: AnimalList = AnimalList()` and rejects code like `l: AnimalList = [Animal(), Animal(), Animal()]`.

Comment: "It is intuitive to create a class here which inherits list." I **strongly** disagree. I don't think a list of Animals needs to do anything that an ordinary list cannot, nor does it need a custom implementation for any of the things that it does normally. The **entire point** of the design of the built-in list is that it **does not care** about the type of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following classes:

```py
class Animal:
    pass


class Cat(Animal):
    pass


class Dog(Animal):
    pass
```

The beauty of the standard collections types like `list`, `tuple` etc. is that since Python 3.9 ([PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/)) they are all "proper" generics, meaning they implement the [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__) method. It returns [**generic alias types**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type).

We can therefore leverage the fact that `list` is already generic in terms of its element type. We simply set up a type variable with an upper bound of `Animal` and then subclass `list` parameterized with that type variable. The subclasses then basically write themselves:

```py
from typing import TypeVar


A = TypeVar("A", bound=Animal)


class AnimalList(list[A]):
    def get_element(self) -> A:
        return self[0]


class CatList(AnimalList[Cat]):
    pass


class DogList(AnimalList[Dog]):
    pass
```

Demo: (pass to mypy)

```py
dl = DogList([Dog()])
cl = CatList([Cat()])
dog = dl.get_element()
cat = cl[0]
reveal_type(dog)  # note: Revealed type is "Dog"
reveal_type(cat)  # note: Revealed type is "Cat"
```

What is nice about this, is that **the only place**, where we need to define the element type of `DogList` is in the specification of the parent class `AnimalList` during subclassing. Of course, if you begin adding `Dog`-specific methods to it, you may need to annotate them properly with `Dog`. But as long as you are just inheriting the methods that are already generic in terms `A`, you don't need to do anything else.

It comes with all the usual typing bells and whistles that `list` has, not just `__getitem__`. If we tried something like `dl.append(Cat())`, the type checker would yell at us. Or if we e.g. implemented a way to sort `Dog` instances and then did something like `sorted_dl = sorted(dl)`, type checkers would infer `sorted_dl` to be a `list[Dog]`. I think you get the idea.

---

As a side note, the [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) upper bound for `A` is not strictly necessary for *this* setup to work, but semantically it makes sense to restrict what type of object the `AnimalList` can hold to `Animal` or a subtype of it. And it becomes *mandatory* to set this bound, once you start relying on that element type in some method.

If you for example defined an attribute on `Animal` like `age: int` and then wanted a method like `get_average_age` on your `AnimalList`, you would have something like this:

```py
class Animal:
    age: int

...

class AnimalList(list[A]):
    ...

    def get_average_age(self) -> float:
        return sum(animal.age for animal in self) / len(self)
```

This would not work without `A` being bounded by `Animal`.

For details about generics in Python, I always refer to the famous [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics).