# What would be the pythonic way to implement a class that represents "a list with a title"?

Tags: python, inheritance, composition, object-composition

I am trying to better understand composition vs inheritance in python so I have crafted a hopefully simple example.

Suppose I want to implement a class `TitledList` that is intended to behave just like a standard list, but with an additional attribute `title` intended to hold a string containing the name of the list. The `__repr__` and `__str__` methods would likely have to be reimplemented to incorporate the title, but otherwise I'd like to retain all the native functionality of `list`. Initializers would accept an optional keyword-only argument `title`.

I can see two approaches to creating this class. I could go the composition route, and define a class with two attributes, `.contents` (a regular list) and `.title`. That would presumably look something along the lines of

```
class TitledList:
    def __init__(self, contents=[], *, title=None):
        self.contents = list(contents)
        self.title = title
```

But I'm not sure how I would go about cribbing all the methods of `list` so I don't have to constantly be referring to `my_titled_list.contents` all over the place or reimplement all the list methods I use.

The other alternative is to do the thing that everyone on the whole Internet [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945940/what-to-consider-before-subclassing-list) [not](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt) [do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), and inherit from the `list` class. I think in that case I would do the initializer like this?

```
class TitledList(list):
    def __init__(self, iterable=[], *, title=None):
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.title = title
```

This seems a lot more straightforward to me. But surely everyone on the whole Internet says not to extend `list` for a *reason*.

What are the pros and cons here? Is there a simple way to make the composition solution work the way I intuitively want? Are there lots of drawbacks to the inheritance solution that I don't understand? Is there some third option I should be considering ([`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList)?)

Comment: Or maybe my inheritance initializer should be `def __init__(self, *args, title=None, **kwargs):` `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: You could possibly try inheriting from [MutableSequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence), delegating the abstract methods to your wrapped list.  This would give you a lot of listy behaviour for free

Comment: This is exactly what `UserList` is for. Use that.

Comment: What should be the result of `a + b`, if `a` is a `TitledList` and `b` is a `list`? Should this be a `list` or a `TitledList`? Same question for `b + a`. And: What if `b` is also a `TitledList`? What should be the `title` of that result?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Obviously those would be questions I would have to answer, but how do they favor one approach over the other? I'd need to figure how to resolve that ambiguity either way.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Not totally sure how to read this page. Is the claim that I only have to explicitly implement `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__len__`, and `insert` and everything else comes for free? It's still a very boring 5 implementations but better 5 than (however many methods `list` has).

Comment: I would say, these questions point to a somewhat conceptual problem of your idea. The nice thing with `list` type is, that there is no ambiguity for these questions. For your `TitledList` you would get problems. I think, this is exactly the reason why `UserList` (if you think about using this) accepts only a constructor with one argument (the list), and no additional parameters.

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea; your implementation of, say, `__getitem__` would be `return self._list.__getitem__[index]`

Comment: I think your second link (https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/) has a pretty good summary of the pitfalls, alternatives, pros, and cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

1. Subclass [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) instead of `list`.  This is basically a wrapper around `list` designed to be extensible.
2. Subclass [`collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) and implement all of the required abstract methods.  This might be useful if you want to define a totally new sequence-like class.
3. Subclass `list`.  This might actually be fine in limited scenarios like your `TitledList` example, where you're just adding a new attribute.  But if you want to ovverride `list`'s existing methods then this may not be a good idea.
4. Create a new object with a list attribute.  This is simple and easy to understand, but might be inconvenient.  It all depends on your use case.

Reference: [Trey Hunner: The problem with inheriting from dict and list in Python](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/why-you-shouldnt-inherit-from-list-and-dict-in-python/)

Comment: As I understand subclassing `collections.abc.MutableSequence`, I should implement `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__len__`, and `insert`, and I will get "a bunch of stuff" for free from the abstract base class. Where is it documented what I get? I'd like to know what methods the `MutableSequence` comes with, both its own as well as any it inherits from further up the inheritance tree.

Comment: For instance, commenter @jonathan.scholbach points out in the question comments that `__add__()` poses some immediate problems. Where in the documentation can I find out if `MutableSequence` defines (or inherits) an implementation for `__add__`?

Comment: @thecommexokid The `collections.abc` documentation includes a table of which abstract methods are specified by each ABC, as well as "mixin" methods for which the ABC provides a default implementation.